# C# and SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-4, rdbms

I have 4 tables from which I am fetching records. The first three tables required inner join with the common rows but with 4th table I need left outer join because I have to preserve the already fetched rows from first three tables.

Now, problem is that I want left join with fourth table but it should only pick the records having date = current date. I am passing current date from C# while calling my stored procedure. But the thing is SQL Server is giving null records.

Here is the query::

```
alter procedure
  (@currentdate varchar(50))
  select distinct 
      table1.name, table2.class,table3.stream 
  from 
      table1
  inner join 
      table 2 on table1.id = table2.id 
  inner join 
      table3 on table3.id=table2.id   
  left outer join 
      table 4 on table 4.id = table3.id and table4.date = @currentdate
```

I used and with left outer join because I want records in that way where as using where clause filters the whole result and just give me one record.

Then also I used casting with both the dates in stored procedure but no positive response.

From C# I'm using

```
var date = datetime.now.toshortdate();
CallStoredProcedure(date)
```

Please help me regarding this ASAP. Thank you

Comment: You should **NOT** use `varchar(50)` as the datatype for a date! **NEVER** ! Use the appropriate types - e.g. `DATETIME`

Comment: See this blog post by Aaron Bertrand on mishandling dates: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you should use the **appropriate** type for your dates - that is `DATETIME` - **do not** cast dates into strings and back if you can avoid it! (and you can definitely avoid it here)

Secondly: the `DATETIME` in SQL Server as well as the `DateTime` in .NET both have dates and time information, e.g.  `2013-06-23 14:57:34` so if you're doing an equality comparison in your JOIN condition, only those rows that **exactly** match your date **and time** will be selected. So you need strip off the time portion, if you want to use just dates for comparison.

So try this code here:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedureNameHere (@currentdate DATETIME)
  SELECT DISTINCT
      table1.name, table2.class, table3.stream 
  FROM
      dbo.table1
  INNER JOIN
      dbo.table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
  INNER JOIN
      dbo.table3 ON table3.id = table2.id   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
      table 4 ON table 4.id = table3.id 
              AND DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, table4.date), 0) = 
                  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @currentdate), 0)
```

This strips off the time portion of your `table4.date` as well as `@currentdate` and then the comparison will be done on **just the date** (no time involved). Once you've updated to SQL Server **2008** or newer, I would recommend to use the `DATE` datatype which is designed exactly for this - storing just the date (no time). Unfortunately, that's not yet available in SQL Server **2005**.

Also, from C# - use this line to call your stored procedure:

```
var date = Datetime.Today;
CallStoredProcedure(date);
```

Comment: Thank You very much for giving your precious time.